# How to search a String Array for a Bracket

Tags: java, android

I know the question has been asked before, but whenever I try to split a string like this:

```
reconvert_array = reconvert.split("//n");
```

And then search the string for a character and attempt to replace it like this:

```
    for (int a = 0; a < reconvert_array.length; a++) {
        reconvert_array[a] = reconvert_array[a].replaceAll("[", " ");


        view_text.setText(Arrays.toString(reconvert_array));

    }
```

I get an error message saying that even though [ is inside of quotation marks it still represents an unclosed character class. Is there a way I can accomplish what I am trying to achieve? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the character, as it is expecting a valid regular expression

```
reconvert_array[a] = reconvert_array[a].replaceAll("\\[", " ");
```